# Can a high-performance jpeglib-turbo implmentation decompress/compress in <100ms?

Tags: libjpeg, libjpeg-turbo

I'm currently implementing a jpeg resizer in C++ using the [jpeglib-turbo](http://libjpeg-turbo.virtualgl.org/) library.

I've been given the target of 100 milli-seconds for JPEG decompression and recompression using the library. The best I can come up with using the recommended optimisation settings (documented in jpeglib-turbo usage.txt) is around 320ms, so I'm wondering is 100ms even possible/realistic? This would be to decompress/recompress an image of 3000x4000 px from around 6Mb in size to 130Kb.

The code that I'm using for fast decompression is:

```
    dinfo.dct_method = JDCT_IFAST;
    dinfo.do_fancy_upsampling = FALSE;
    dinfo.two_pass_quantize = FALSE;
    dinfo.dither_mode = JDITHER_ORDERED;
    dinfo.scale_num = 1/8;
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need it to be so fast? 320ms for a 6MB JPEG is pretty speedy.

Comment: You haven't mentioned a platform. Is this for mobile? desktop? single or multithreaded? I have some fast "DCT thumbnail" code that I've been working on. On my 2GHz Core i7 (using a single thread), it can extract a 1/8 sized RGB32 image from 6 megabytes of JPEG data (a 4000x4000 image) in about 120ms. To recompress that 500x500 image to 130KB would probably take another 40-100ms (I haven't done extreme optimization on the compressor yet). The time-critical portion of thumbnail extract code is written in 64-bit assembly language. Contact me for more info (bitbank@pobox.com).

Comment: is this project open source by any chance? post a link :)

Comment: The first thing I notice is that `dinfo.scale_num = 1/8` is in fact equivalent to `dinfo.scale_num = 0` because of integer aritmetics in C++.

Comment: What type is `dinfo`? Which machine were you running your code? And, you should make clear you were targeting to downscale the input image by a factor 8, which is not really jpeg compression (although supported by the libjpeg library).

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the answers.

It is actually possible to decompress and re-compress in around 100ms. After contacting the writer of libjpeg-turbo he told me that the dinfo.scale_num property I was using was wrong. This property is the scale **numerator** - I also needed to set the **scale_denom** (denominator) property.

So the good code would be:

```
 dinfo.dct_method = JDCT_IFAST;
 dinfo.do_fancy_upsampling = FALSE;
 dinfo.two_pass_quantize = FALSE;
 dinfo.dither_mode = JDITHER_ORDERED;
 dinfo.scale_num = 1;
 dinfo.scale_denom = 8;
```

I want the code to be so fast as the image scaling should be imperceptible for the user as it's in a client application where speed/user-experience is the most important thing.